# Access Switchboard routing duplicate work to employees

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an access database with 30+ users working from the same parts of a switchboard as a work router. It is typical for them to get an error that another user has already updated something they are working on. The DB is already split, I'm unsure of why they would be having this problem though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because someone is changing the **page** they are working on (see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0deb1d84-f3d8-4572-8a64-4420da24ebfd/fatal-bug-in-access-2007-locks?forum=accessdev) for a more in depth discussion).

Access operates in pages for locking, not records, as default. (Page = 4096 bytes in Jet 4+, and 2048 in previous versions)

To fix this issue, turn on row locking.

In Access 2010 the option is found by file->options->client settings

The check box is

```
[x]   Open database by using record-level locking.
```

If you don't use above option, then access defaults to page locking.

Comment: We already have this option selected